# Stack is sorted with O(N)

Tags: java, sorting, stack

I'm creating a method to test if a given stack is sorted or not. I've completed the main task of the program but is there a way to implement this algorithm without having O(N^2). I would like to get this one with O(N). Does such a solution exist? If so can someone point me in the right direction.

Some rules
- Only one auxiliary stack can be made.
- No additional data structures.
- If a stack is empty or has one item it is assumed to be sorted.
- Must perform in **O(N)**

```
public static boolean isSorted(Stack s){

    boolean sorted = true;
    Stack backup = new Stack();

    int prev, curr;

    if(s.isEmpty() || s.size() == 1) {

        sorted = true;  

    } else {

        while(!s.isEmpty()){

            prev = s.pop();
            backup.push(prev);

            curr = s.pop();
            backup.push(curr);

            if(prev > curr && sorted)
                sorted = false;

        }

    }

    while(!backup.isEmpty()) {
        s.push(backup.pop());
    }


    return sorted;

}
```

Sample Input: {20,20,17,11,9,8,3,2}

Output:

```
 top 2 3 8 9 11 17 20 20 bottom
| isSorted = true
| top 2 3 8 9 11 17 20 20 bottom
```

At the end of the function. The stack given should be in its original state. I just have to get this in O(N)

Comment: Subclass Stack, override `push` to flip a flag from sorted to unsorted if it sees a value out of line. No computation required after that. *O(1)* after all those little comparison costs are amortized in.

Comment: Not my downvote, but can't you just pop each item off the stack and make sure everything is in sequence?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am popping the values and making sure everything is in sequence, as well pushing everything into a backup stack. Then finally pushing everything back into the original stack.

Comment: You can do it with a recursive function, this avoids the additional popping and you can switch the original stack with the backup stack, but I guess that depends on the definition of O if it would be linear in time (certainly not space)

Comment: Your answer is BTW O(N)

Comment: @eckes is it? :/ how?

Comment: If you have 1000 elements it will pop them 2*1000 and push them 2*1000, that's O(4N) which is linear cost. (You do. have a Bug in there as you always pop twice which does not work for odd sized stacks other than 1)

Comment: @eckes Perhaps my understanding of BigO is frickle. I recently started learning about it. Thank you for the clarification. I shall find a way to fix that bug, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept you're presenting here is not O(n<sup>2</sup>), but indeed O(n) - for each element of the stack you perform a constant number of operations, regardless of the size of N.

You should note, however, that you have a bug there - on each iteration of the loop you pop two elements and compare them, so you're effectively testing only if each pair of elements is sorted, not the entire set (e.g., try this algorithm with the values {2, 1, 500, 400}). Additionally, note that consecutive equal values don't break sorting, so you should use `>=` instead of `>`. Another optimization could be to fail fast once you detect the stack is unsorted:

```
public static boolean isSorted(Stack s) {

    boolean sorted = true;
    Stack backup = new Stack();

    int prev;
    int curr = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    while (!s.isEmpty() && sorted) {
        prev = curr;
        curr = s.pop();
        backup.push(curr);
        sorted = (prev <= curr);
    }

    while (!backup.isEmpty()) {
        s.push(backup.pop());
    }

    return sorted;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! @eckes made me aware of my running time. It makes more sense to me. Also thank you for making me understand my bug. So If I were to encounter an out of order stack in the first half, I would simply stop searching further and push back all the items from backup. That makes it more efficient, regardless of whether it's worse case is O(N) in my case. Appreciate it!

Comment: In retrospect, the initial size check is redundant - I'll remove it.